# linux red-hat 7.1 version + dropped increasing from ifconfig

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, ifconfig

please advice what could be the root cause for dropped increasing problem?

as the following: ( we see dropped 2201101 , and this value increased evry sec ....) on Linux red-hat 7.1

```
    eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
    inet 12.196.92.19  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 12.196.92.255
    ether 01:j0:56:9f:01:2d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 232527230  bytes 1889668645608 (1.7 TiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2201101  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 197267008  bytes 455540267580 (424.2 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



  ethtool -S eth1
  NIC statistics:
  Tx Queue#: 0
     TSO pkts tx: 0
     TSO bytes tx: 0
     ucast pkts tx: 27261
     ucast bytes tx: 5684138
     mcast pkts tx: 0
     mcast bytes tx: 0
     bcast pkts tx: 6
     bcast bytes tx: 252
     pkts tx err: 0
     pkts tx discard: 0
     drv dropped tx total: 0
       too many frags: 0
       giant hdr: 0
       hdr err: 0
       tso: 0
     ring full: 0
     pkts linearized: 0
     hdr cloned: 0
     giant hdr: 0
    Tx Queue#: 1
      TSO pkts tx: 0
      TSO bytes tx: 0
      ucast pkts tx: 138
      ucast bytes tx: 12312
      mcast pkts tx: 0
      mcast bytes tx: 0
      bcast pkts tx: 0
      bcast bytes tx: 0
      pkts tx err: 0
      pkts tx discard: 0
      drv dropped tx total: 0
         too many frags: 0
         giant hdr: 0
         hdr err: 0
         tso: 0
      ring full: 0
      pkts linearized: 0
      hdr cloned: 0
      giant hdr: 0
    Rx Queue#: 0
      LRO pkts rx: 0
      LRO byte rx: 0
      ucast pkts rx: 123
      ucast bytes rx: 10936
      mcast pkts rx: 0
      mcast bytes rx: 0
      bcast pkts rx: 13496
      bcast bytes rx: 859036
      pkts rx OOB: 0
      pkts rx err: 0
     drv dropped rx total: 0
        err: 0
       fcs: 0
       rx buf alloc fail: 0
      Rx Queue#: 1
      LRO pkts rx: 2613
      LRO byte rx: 40902978
      ucast pkts rx: 27979
      ucast bytes rx: 128670918
      mcast pkts rx: 0
      mcast bytes rx: 0
      bcast pkts rx: 255
      bcast bytes rx: 34445
      pkts rx OOB: 0
      pkts rx err: 0
      drv dropped rx total: 0
      err: 0
      fcs: 0
      rx buf alloc fail: 0
      tx timeout count: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The increasing "dropped" counter means your system receives from the network many packets that it deems "junk". The most common example are packets that are not addressed to the interface's IP (or broadcast IP or multicast IPs).

Your IP address smells bad - this is an Internet address, and the system might be open to the Internet right now. Make sure it's properly secured, the first step being the firewalld (Internet-facing interface shouldn't be in "private" firewalld zone).

Once you are secured and still would like to see what those packets are, you need to log them using wireshark/tshark. While you use the tool, it will change the interface to process anything that would be otherwise "dropped" (aka promiscuous mode).

```
yum install wireshark
tshark -nni eth1
```

Once you take a look at the results, you would most probably conclude that there is nothing wrong with these packets being dropped; that's OK.